# password_hash не работает с файлами?

Tags: php, файлы

Если вместо $a написать пароль в строку 'admsh1216hs' и сравнить он сработает, но после прочтения из файла сравнивать не хочет , это баг?
Файл читается , права на чтение есть.

```
$hello = 'admsahra1216hs';



$a = file_get_contents('content/pss.txt');
echo $a;
if (password_verify($hello, $a)) {
    echo "True<br>";
}
else {
    echo "err";
}
```

Comment: Кодировка и BOM?

Comment: нет , я на linux , тут по дефаулту без BOM gedit должен сохранять

Comment: Думаю просто в файле есть символ переноса на новую строку. +1 символ. `admsh1216hs` vs `admsh1216hs\n`

Comment: нету , проверил это первым долгом)

Comment: т.е `$b === $hello //true` ?

Comment: я подкорректировал код , посмотрите

Comment: pss.txt содержит hash строки admsahra1216hs , если вместо переменной вставить в password_veridy просто сравниваемую строку в ковычках , все работает , а с переменной и file_get_contents нет

Comment: Если верить докам то сначала строка потом хэш. `password_verify($a, $hello)` -> `password_verify($hello, $a)`. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php

Comment: да , я так и делал просто ошибься пока писал вопрос , поправил вопрос,  все равно не работает)

Comment: а если вместо $a вставить вот эту строку в одинарные кавычки то сработает $2y$10$EQlvE.sJQ6DmZKg9aTj3beOaI0DLaD2QU97D2k6CI3CDW/xPottbS

Comment: Попробуйте добавить трим. `$a = trim(file_get_contents('content/pss.txt'));` Что бы не зависеть от редактора.

Comment: trim изначально стоял, не помогло

Comment: $oldlog = stripslashes($oldlog);
 $oldlog = htmlspecialchars($oldlog);
 $oldlog = strip_tags($oldlog);
 $oldlog = trim($oldlog);

Answer (score 0):

Решено, Создал текстовые документы через Netbeans IDE pss.txt и заработало , видимо проблема была все же в BOM.

```
P.S Видимо gedit тот что на UBUNTU не далеко ушел от notepad.exe на Windows
```